# Flutter - List of Containers side by side

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to display a list of `Container`s with text side by side in Flutter.

I tried doing a `ListView` but it didn't achieve my goal it instead span the list horizontally. Yes I know when you set `scrollDirection` to Horizontal` it allows users to scroll horizontally if the list of items overflow.

```
                       Container(
                          height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(100),
                          child: ListView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            children: col.map((colName) {
                              return GestureDetector(
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                  child: buildSkillText(
                                      Colors.blue[300], colName),
                                ),
                                onTap: () => {},
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        )
```

**This is what I want to achieve** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Wrap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget.

Example code:

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  children: col.map((colName) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: buildSkillText(
            Colors.blue[300], colName),
      ),
      onTap: () => {},
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, dumb question... And yes that's exactly what I'm looking for! But how will I be able to dynamically add Chip in, base on a list?

Comment: I updated my answer to show something similar to what you're doing with ListView.