# How to fill contents inside wrap widget?

Tags: flutter

I want to move widgets to the new line automatically if it's overflow and `Wrap` widget is a good way for this.

so I have some wrap widgets which have width based on text length and some icons like:

Current actual:
[image: My current widgets]

I want to align 2 icons on the left and right side of the parent.

but as you can see the red-colored area of `Row`, I don't know how to make `Row` width match to the parent when `Text` widget has longer than `Row` (in the above case of the attached image, `something?`)

This is what I expect:
[image]

and my current code is:

```
Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "hoge",
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.edit),
                  Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "too long text...............",
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.edit),
                  Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                "hoge",
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.edit),
                  Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ],
),
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IntrinsicWidth(
    child: Column(
        children: [
            Text(
                "too long text...............",
            ),
            Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                    Icon(Icons.edit),
                    Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                ],
            )
        ],
    ),
),
```

Wrap your long text Column with IntrinsicWidth instead of normal Container Widget.moreover, remove the mainAxisSize constraint on the Row widget to make it's width same as Text widget.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for [List of Containers side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549539/flutter-list-of-containers-side-by-side)

I made it dynamic so that you can add new items if you want base on the list of **Item**.

```
class Item {
  String text;
  IconData icon1;
  IconData icon2;
  Color color;

  Item({ this.text, this.icon1, this.icon2,this.color,});
}
```

We can make this dynamic by creating a **List** of **Item**

```
final List<Item> item = [
    Item(
      text: 'Item 3',
      icon1: Icons.edit,
      icon2: Icons.more_vert,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Item(
      text: 'Item 2 This text is too long for the screen width..... screen width.....screen width.....screen width.....',
      icon1: Icons.edit,
      icon2: Icons.more_vert,
      color: Colors.greenAccent,
    ),
    Item(
      text: 'Item 3',
      icon1: Icons.edit,
      icon2: Icons.more_vert,
      color: Colors.amberAccent[100],
    ),
  ];
```

You might also want to look at [Wrap Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)

```
Wrap(
    spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
    runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
    children: item.map((Item) {
      return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Item.color,
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(Item.text),
              Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Item.icon1),
                  Icon(Item.icon2),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => {},
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried your advice but it doesn't work and I'm sorry for my lack of explanation. updated my description.